# Azure DevTestLabs custom Image error "Creating a virtual machine from Marketplace image requires Plan information in the request"

Tags: image, azure, azure-devtest-labs

In Azure DevTestlabs I have made a custom image from a market resource (CIS hardened image) and saved it to blob storage. After this I want to create a VM from this image (and do other things with the image).

I have this process automated through Azure Pipeline which was working until three months ago. A few days ago I gave it another spin and it fails on creating the VMs.

Since the custom image was created, instead of going through my scripting I decided to create a VM from the portal.

Now when I try to create a VM from the image in the portal I get the following error:
`Creating a virtual machine from Marketplace image requires Plan information in the request`

Did anyone run into this or have any ideas where to look for a solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The plan resource does not exist for Microsoft.DevTestLab labs/virtualmachines template

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.devtestlab/2018-09-15/labs/virtualmachines

Try re-creating the custom image and try again.